# Adjust height and weight of a box according to windows size in shiny

Tags: shiny, rstudio

I am trying this code for automatically adjust height and weight of a box according to windows size i.e., while maximizing the window, the box in my shiny app should also adjust its size.

```
tabitems(
 tabItem(tabName = "plot1", 
       box( width = "100%" , height = "100%", solidHeader = FALSE, status = "primary",
         plotOutput("plot"))
)
```

The width of the box is changing its size according to the app window size but the height isn't?

Answer (score 3):

Note that the documentation for `plotOutput` says "Note that, for height, using "auto" or "100%" generally will not work as expected, because of how height is computed with HTML/CSS."

Here's a solution that uses JavaScript in order to calculate the height of the browser's window, save that number as a Shiny input, and use it as the `height` of `plotOutput`.  Keep in mind there might be other approaches, and I'd love to see what else can be done, but this is what first came to mind.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)

shinyjscode <- "
shinyjs.init = function() {
  $(window).resize(shinyjs.calcHeight);
}
shinyjs.calcHeight = function() { 
  Shiny.onInputChange('plotHeight', $(window).height());
}
"

runApp(shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    shinyjs::useShinyjs(),
    shinyjs::extendShinyjs(text = shinyjscode),
    plotOutput("plot")
  ),
  server = function(input, output, session) {
    plotHeight <- reactive({ 
      ifelse(is.null(input$plotHeight), 0, input$plotHeight)
    })

    output$plot <- renderPlot({
      plot(1:10)
    },
    height = plotHeight)

    js$calcHeight()
  }
))
```

Comment: it would be great if you could provide the code for fixing the size of the Box in RShiny

Comment: This works fantastically!  The `extendShinyjs` function now requires a functions argument such that the following should be (or at least can be) substituted into the fluidPage function:

`extendShinyjs(text = shinyjscode, functions = c("init", "calcHeight")`

Comment: Only if V8 package is not installed

Comment: Not sure what V8 means in @DeanAttali comment. This works pretty well, except that I'm having problems with plotHeight not being a numeric in some cases. Usually, you need to use plotHeight() for a reactive, not plotHeight directly. But if I use height=plotHeight() I get an error:
Operation not allowed without an active reactive context. (You tried to do something that can only be done from inside a reactive expression or observer.)