# navbarPage - collapse some tabs into menu in shiny app

Tags: css, r, twitter-bootstrap, tabs, shiny

I have a shiny app (using bootstrap) with several tabPanels within navbarPage and some of them are not really important:

```
runApp(
  list(
    ui = navbarPage(theme = 'bootstrap.css',
                    position = 'fixed-top',
                    collapsible = TRUE,
                    'There is a title of this app',
                    tabPanel('tabPanel1'),
                    tabPanel('tabPanel2'),
                    tabPanel('tabPanel3'),
                    tabPanel('tabPanel4'),
                    tabPanel('tabPanel5'),
                    tabPanel('tabPanel6'),
                    tabPanel('tabPanel7'),
                    tabPanel('tabPanel8 - not important'),
                    tabPanel('tabPanel9 - not important')),
    server = function(input, output){

    }
  )
)
```

The problem is that when using smaller window/screen, the tabs and title are in two lines and they are collapsed only when window is really small. Other thing is that all of them are collapsed at once, not tab by tab.

So the optimal solution would be to collapse them into menu tab by tab. Another acceptable solution would be to collapse not important tabs in menu by default regardless of window size.

I'm quite new in this area, so I would appreciate any help (dummies-friendly ones are especially welcomed).

Comment: You could combine: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31901910/adjust-height-and-weight-of-a-box-according-to-windows-size-in-shiny and https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/shiny-discuss/Coe8drGPJbU/5JXdisgVFAAJ,...

Comment: Thanks for answer! By combining you mean to create condition for resizing window and then hide extra tabs? Well, the first part is OK, but the second just hides the tabs and does not collapse them into menu, so the user won't be able to use those tabs. This is not really what I want. Or do I understand it wrong?